# Javascript or Python? beginner getting up to speed

Tags: javascript, python

Which language will allow a beginner to get up to speed quicker?

Basically which language of the two is easier to learn

Comment: Both of them. BTW, you're comparing apples with oranges in there.

Comment: Rather than focusing only on the time to "get up to speed" (which is anyway somewhat subjective and, concerning this specific pair of languages somewhat too close to call), you should consider your immediate needs (which kind of application would you like to build) and/or your longer term goals (which language will expose you to a broader set of concepts, problems etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is more regular, and has not needed to keep supporting every old, redundant feature forever, as Javascript has been forced to do (in order to keep supporting existing sites): these are issues that can make Python easier to learn.

However, Javascript's not too bad, especially if you can choose a reasonably rigid, modular, clean framework such as dojo (if you have to learn about *every* popular JS framework, or even most of them, it will, however, be a nightmare -- as it will if you have to learn the subtle bugs and incompatibilities of various browsers' implementations of JS and the DOM, rather than getting them covered up by such frameworks as dojo, jquery, or closure).

For learning Javascript, I recommend supplementing whatever tutorial you choose with Crockford's [Javascript: the good parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) -- it's a very *thin* book (which sounds like a joke, but it's true!-), fast and easy to read, and stops you from wasting your time on language features that are misconceived, too badly designed to use, or counterproductive. Crockford is a real JS guru and is well worth reading and paying attention to.

Comment: +1 for JavaScript: The Good Parts

Answer (score 10):

Depends what you want to do. If you're just interested in learning a programming language, I would recommend Python because:

- The interactive prompt is great for learning a language
- It's simple and well-designed, whereas JavaScript has a number of design flaws that can be confusing to newbies
- There is a particularly high amount of introductory materials for Python.
- It allows you to do all kinds of programming (server, client, games, etc.), whereas JS will limit you a bit more.

Comment: Note that both Firefox and Chrome have interactive Javascript prompts available as well. (Chrome via Developer Tools, Firefox via Firebug.)

Comment: On the other hand JS will set the path for other languages (in terms on syntaxes), while python won't.

Comment: I  would like to do various things such as make plugins for browser, dating site etc........

Comment: Also Python's natural indentation based syntax will get you thinking properly about logical order and scope

Comment: It sounds like you will need to learn a bit of both. JS for the browser plugins I think, and Python for the back end of your dating site.

Answer (score 4):

They're both pretty straightforward to learn. They more differ in terms of their typical project space - Javascript is usually utilized more for the client-side portion of web applications, while Python is often utilized for the server side of web applications and also standalone non-web apps.

What do you want to make?

Answer (score 2):

The two languages are used for two completely different purposes. JavaScript does work in the browser,<sup>1</sup> Python does work everywhere else. Pick the language based on which you want; it's useless to learn a language if you can't even use it for your project. If you want to make a website, for example, you'll have to learn both--JavaScript for the client and Python for the server.

Regardless, to answer your question, both languages are great but I'd say Python is easier to start with. JavaScript's basics are fine, but it features a lot of advanced concepts that you shouldn't have to deal with when learning your first language, IMO.

<sup>1. Yes, I'm aware that you can use JavaScript on the server-side, but those implementations are not mature and certainly not for a beginner. Python is much more suited for that kind of thing.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

PHP is my thing, but I've played with Python and worked with JS. Being only somewhat skilled in both languages, Python feels nice and clean (although a little wierd) with the forced tabbing conventions and lack of semicolons. JS, on the other hand makes me feel like I need a shower. Especially after debugging in IE.

But the only real answer is the question - What do you want to do with it? Want to make websites do cool things in the browser? Go with JS. Something else? Maybe Python is better suited, as @Amber said.

Edit: As for getting up to speed, here's how it works. Your first language takes you a longer time to learn. Your second takes much less time, and after that it's not long at all since you're mostly just learning new syntax for similar things. So the solution for getting up to speed faster is to jump in right now.

Comment: it isn't "forced tabbing" it is indentions, and you should only use SPACES

Comment: Haha, it was late, and I could not think of the word indent for some reason. As for using spaces, well I have to disagree with you there. Tabs are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would say JavaScript is easy to learn. I had to learn it to program the Karotz. It only took about 2 months of Youtube tutorials to learn most of it.